# Basic Twitter Data Mining Causing Problem

Tags: twitter, tweepy

This is my first attempt to extract tweets using twitter api and tweepy. When I execute my code it keep printing 401 every time in a new line. What am I doing wrong is I am not able to figure out. Any help is appreciated.

```
import tweepy
import json
access_token = ""
access_token_secret = ""
consumer_key = ""
consumer_secret = ""
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key,consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token,access_token_secret)
class MyStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
    def __init__(self, api=None):
        super(MyStreamListener, self).__init__()
        self.num_tweets = 0
        self.file = open("tweets.txt", "w")

    def on_status(self, status):
        tweet = status._json
        self.file.write( json.dumps(tweet) + '\n' )
        self.num_tweets += 1
        if self.num_tweets < 100:
            return True
        else:
            return False
        self.file.close()

    def on_error(self, status):
        print(status)
l = MyStreamListener()
stream=tweepy.Stream(auth,l)
stream.filter()
tweets_data_path = 'tweets.txt'
tweets_file = open(tweets_data_path, "r")
tweets_data = []
for line in tweets_file:
    tweet = json.loads(line)
    tweets_data.append(tweet)
tweets_file.close()
print(tweets_data[0].keys())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to your twitter account settings and change timezone to that as of your computer. Then, go to twitter app settings and generate new consumer key and new access token. These newly generated keys and tokens you should use to avoid 401 error.